# Getting last part of a string

Tags: java

I have a string in following format

```
String s= abc=1,cde=2,efg=3
```

I only want to extract `efg`.
I tried by Spilting it but not getting `3` in last part for `part[3]`  it is showing arrays out of bounds exception.  I want to extract as I need to increment last part by `1` every time.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Why do you think the last part would be in `part[3]`? Since when are array indices 1-based?

Comment: Try `part[2]` and check.

Answer (score 0):

If split() results in an array of three elements, the index of the last one is 2 not 3. That could explain the exception. In an array indexes start at 0.

Comment: How to do it with given string.. I want only last value of every string in this case it is 3

Comment: Subtract 1 from the length of the array to obtain the index of the last element: `String lastElement = yourArray[yourArray.length - 1];`